# Mocking File.listFiles using Mockito3.3.3 and Junit 5.6

Tags: mockito, junit5

Method for testing

```
    public int check() {
        File f =new File("as.txt");
        File[] arr = f.listFiles();
        return arr.length;
    }
```

Test class

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class TestDataService {

    @InjectMocks
    private DataService dataService;
    
    @Test
    void chett() {
        File[] arr = {new File("we.txt")};
        File ff =Mockito.mock(File.class);
        when(ff.listFiles()).thenReturn(arr);
        assertEquals(1, dataService.check());
    }
}
```

I am getting null pointer exception at File[] arr = f.listFiles();

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the implementation of your `check()` method

```
public int check() {
     File f = new File("C:\\");
     File[] arr = f.listFiles();
     return arr.length;
}
```

As per `listFiles()` documentations it should contain the directory, otherwise it will return you `null`.
`If this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, then this method returns null. Otherwise, an array of File objects is returned, one for each file or directory in the directory. Pathnamesdenoting the directory itself and the directory's parent directory are not included in the result.`

Then you can create your test class like this

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class TestDataService {

    @InjectMocks
    private DataService dataService;
    
    @Mock
    private File f;

    @Test
    void chett() {
        File[] arr = { new File("C://") };
        when(f.listFiles()).thenReturn(arr);
        assertEquals(1, dataService.check());
    }
}
```

OR this

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class TestDataService {

    @InjectMocks
    private DataService dataService;
    
    @Mock
    private File f;

    @Test
    void chett() {
        File[] arr = { new File("C://") };
        File ff = Mockito.mock(File.class);
        when(ff.listFiles()).thenReturn(arr);
        assertEquals(1, dataService.check());
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding Path return result but still I am not able to mock listFiles when(ff.listFiles()).thenReturn(arr);
As I want to return arr when actual listFile method is called from check()